# Explicitly calling edit on a treeView cell

Tags: java, treeview, javafx-2

I am implementing a custom cellFactory on a TreeView component and I would like to call the `startEdit()` function on a certain tree item. According to the javaFX documentation, the following method should work:

```
// "Item Title" is the title of the item to be edited
tree.edit(new TreeItem<String>("Item Title"));
```

But nothing happens when I use it. I am only able to start the editing mode by double clicking the tree item itself, and I would like to be able to call this function automatically when the user creates a new treeItem:

```
// Create a new TreeItem
TreeItem<String> item = new TreeItem<String> ("New Item");
// Insert it to the current tree
tree.getRoot().getChildren().add(item);
// Enter edit mode
tree.edit(item);
```

Comment: Providing a SSCCE (with your cell factory) will be more helpful.

Comment: @UlukBiy it's a basic cell factory implementation with the methods `startEdit()`, `commitEdit()` etc. How can I call those functions from the containing tree?

Comment: it's a bug, see http://stackoverflow.com/q/29863095/203657